# Software capable of synchronizing video sources

Tags: video, sync, editing

Do you know of any video editing software that makes synchronizing multiple sources of video easy?

Often I get a few files from each camera used to record an event. The files I get aren't continuous but they overlap. My job is to review the video and choose the best angles, quality, etc.  For example. the files I may get (pardon my ASCII art skills) may resemble this pattern (each series of numbers is a separate file):

```
| full length         |
_________________________

 11111 22222 3333 4   5   (camera 1)
666  777                  (camera 2)
    8888888888  9999999   (camera 3)
```

Software I'm looking for would have a smart synchronization feature where I could tell it "The first second of the first file corresponds to somewhere between the 25th and the 30th second of the second file. I want you to figure it out exactly and adjust the position of the files on the timeline."

With the technology we have nowadays I think it should be easy, but I evaluated several programs (CyberLink PowerDirector, Corel VideoStudio, Adobe Premiere Elements, Magix Movie Edit Pro, Pinnacle Studio) and found no such functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two suggestions:

1: Commercial: [Vegas Pro 9](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/vegaspro) (US$599.95)

[image: image1]

2: Open source : [Blender](http://www.blender.org/).
Although mainly a 3D content creation suite, it's said to contain a powerful [Video Sequence Editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Sequencer/Usage).

Comment: Oh my, this one's expensive!